# Rank of composite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two complex (general non-invertible) $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, and the fact that the $n\times 2n$ composite matrix $(A,B)$ is rank $n$, how do I show that for all $\phi,\phi'\in\mathbb{C}^n$, $\phi,\phi'\neq0$
$$A\phi +B\phi'\neq0$$

Comment: It's not clear what statement exactly you're trying to prove. Generally speaking, there **does exist** a pair $\phi,\phi' \in \Bbb C^n$ such that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are non-zero but $A\phi + B\phi' = 0$, contradicting the statement that it appears that you're trying to prove.

Comment: To rephrase: it's not clear what you're asking, but if my best guess is correct, then the statement you're trying to prove is incorrect.

Comment: It is from this paper [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9806013v2) lemma 2.3. He mentions that the range of (A,B) is all of $C^n$. I cannot see why that proves that $\chi=0$ @BenGrossmann (Note that I am not math oriented. Maybe its plain obvious)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, he question seems to revolve around understanding the proof of Lemma 2.3 [from this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9806013v2), so I will address that underlying question directly.

The proof begins by stating that if $A + i\sqrt{E}B$ fails to be invertible, then there must be a **non-zero** vector $\chi \in \Bbb C^n$ such that $(A^\dagger - i\sqrt{E}B^\dagger)\chi = 0$. It then shows as a consequence that this $\chi$ would satisfy $A^\dagger \chi = B^\dagger \chi = 0$. From here, it uses the fact that the composite matrix $[A\ \ B]$ has full rank to derive a contradiction.

One way to understand this is as follows. First, note that $A^\dagger \chi = B^\dagger \chi = 0$ means that $\chi$ is an element of the orthogonal complements of both the images of $A$ and $B$. In other words, for every $\phi \in \Bbb C^n$, we have
$$
\langle \chi, A \phi\rangle = \langle A^\dagger \chi,\phi\rangle = \langle 0,\phi\rangle = 0
$$
and similarly, $\langle\chi,B\phi \rangle = 0$. On the other hand, the image of the map $(A,B):\Bbb C^{2n} \to \Bbb C^n$ is all of $\Bbb C^n$. In other words, for every vector $\psi \in \Bbb C^n$, the equation
$$
\pmatrix{A & B} \pmatrix{\phi\\\phi'} = \psi\\
(\text{or equivalently } A\phi + B\phi' = \psi)
$$
has at least one solution (for $\phi,\phi' \in \Bbb C^n$).

Now, one way to see that there is a contradiction between these to points is to note that there exist $\phi,\phi' \in \Bbb C^n$ such that $A\phi + B\phi' = \chi$. With that, we find that
\begin{align}
\|\chi\|^2 &= \langle \chi,\chi \rangle = \langle \chi, A\phi + B\phi' \rangle 
\\ &= \langle \chi, A\phi\rangle + \langle \chi,B\phi' \rangle = 0+0 = 0.
\end{align}
But $\chi$ was supposed to be a non-zero vector, which means that $\|\chi\| \neq 0$, hence our contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much! That definitely cleared it up.